# Why `all(round(x(:)) == x(:))` instead of `round(x) == x` for scalar x?

Tags: matlab

I came across the following snippet of code in the MATLAB distribution (`matlab.internal.tableUtils.isScalarInt` of R2013b; the `% etc.` comments indicate omitted code):

```
function [tf,isInt] = isScalarInt(x,lower,upper)
if isscalar(x)
    isInt = isnumeric(x) && all(round(x(:)) == x(:));
    if nargin == 1
        % etc.
    elseif nargin == 2
        tf = isInt && all(x(:) >= lower);
    else % nargin == 3
        tf = isInt && all((lower <= x(:)) & (x(:) <= upper));
    end
else
    % etc.
end
end
```

I'm puzzled by all the uses of `all` and `x(:)` in this code, considering that it may assume that `isscalar(x)` is `true`.  What's wrong with just

```
function [tf,isInt] = isScalarInt(x,lower,upper)
if isscalar(x)
    isInt = isnumeric(x) && round(x) == x;
    if nargin == 1
        % etc.
    elseif nargin == 2
        tf = isInt && x >= lower;
    else % nargin == 3
        tf = isInt && lower <= x && x <= upper;
    end
else
    % etc.
end
end
```

?

Actually, I suppose that using `all` for the comparisons against `lower` and `upper` would enable the function to sensibly handle non-scalar `lower` and `upper` arguments, but I still don't see what difference it makes to use `all` in the comparison involving `round` (which involves only scalars).  Ditto for the repeated use of `x(:)` instead of just `x`: as far as I can tell, the results would be identical if `x(:)` were replaced with `x` everywhere in this code...

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything.  You understand this code better than whoever wrote it.

Comment: The code you are showing looks like a typical product of code generation mechanisms. Your understanding of the code is totally correct.

Comment: Not to mention that `lower` and `upper` are the names of reasonably common built-in functions...

Comment: @horchler: in this case `lower` and `upper` are input arguments.

Comment: @Daniel: thanks, that explains it nicely.  I'll gladly accept your answer if you care to post it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assume that `x` is a scalar. The function `isScalarInt` is checking if all the **elements** of `x` are scalars, not whether `x` itself is a scalar. Therefore

- `all(round(x(:)) == x(:))` is not equal to `round(x(:)) == x(:)` because the former is a scalar logical value, the latter can be a vector of logical values.
- `all(...)` works column-wise. If `x` is a matrix, for example, `all` will return a row vector of logical values.  In order to get a scalar from `all` (i.e., to test **all** elements of `x`), you first need to vectorize the variable `x` by doing `x(:)`.

Therefore both `all` and `x(:)` are needed in this function.

Comment: The question is about the first block of code which is contained within a check for `isscalar(x)`. Within that block, `x` itself can only be a scalar. The OP wasn't asking what `isScalarInt` does, but rather why the code in that block seems superfluous. `all` and `x(:)` are *not* needed within the first `if` statement block that the OP asked about.